# Neo4j shell: how to run an existing DB?

Tags: shell, neo4j

After starting Neo4j shell I cannot really access my DB, which is though accessible from web interface.

```
$ ./bin/neo4j-shell -path Users/username/Downloads/neo4j-community-2.0.1/data/graph.db
NOTE: Local Neo4j graph database service at 'Users/username/Downloads/neo4j-community-2.0.1/data/graph.db'
Welcome to the Neo4j Shell! Enter 'help' for a list of commands


neo4j-sh (?)$ cd -a 1
Node 0 not found
```

There is still this question mark **neo4j-sh (?)$** apparently meaning that there is no DB to explore. At the same time I got no error messages... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think there is something wrong. You simply don't have any data in your DB

Comment: then how come that I can browse the DB in the same location via web interface?

Comment: And do you have any data when browsing via the we interface ? You also have a shell console in the web interface, doesn't it behave similarly  to your local shell ?

Comment: I do have data in my DB and I can browse it via the web-interface ("Data-browser"), but I cannot see it under any kind of shell, not under the one in the web interface, nor under the local one.

Comment: Have you tried to 'cd' in a node that you are sure you have by using the web shell ?

Comment: Oh, thank you for this hint! I thought the shell counts nodes starting from 0 for the root, but I tried "13410" - the number that Neo4j somehow attributes to my root node, and it works! By the way, do you know, where those big numbers come from? I added only 8 nodes manually, and here I get 13410...

Comment: By the way, I then tried to run the same command, cd -a 13410, in the loacal shell and received the error message "Node 13410 not found"

Comment: There is no root node in neo4j 2.0. The big numbers may come from adding and deleting nodes, as neo4j may increase the ids and not necessary re-use them. If you try with a brand new DB, the first node that you'll create will probably have the id 1.

Comment: Sorry I am having the same problem: how did you solve it?